# Avoid propagation of NA in matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, missing-data

I have some difficulties with propagation of missing values in the context of matrix multiplication. 
My first matrix `X` is the gas flow measurements each hour for 5 flowmeters:

```
X=structure(c(16, 19, 28, 32, 30, 22, 16, 13, 8, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 6, 13, 7, 10, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, -16, -17, -20, -31, -25, -25, -16, -12, -13, -15, -9, -7), .Dim = c(12L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("meter1", "meter2", "meter3", "meter4", "meter5")))
####      meter1 meter2 meter3 meter4 meter5
#### [1,]     16      5      0      7    -16
#### [2,]     19      5      0      8    -17
#### ...
```

My second matrix `Z` says how these gas flows are distributed to feed 4 cities: for instance (first column of `Z`), for city1 the total net flow is defined as the sum of `(1)*Meter1 + (-1)*Meter2 + (1)*Meter5`.

```
Z=structure(c(1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city4")))
####      city1 city2 city3 city4
#### [1,]     1     0     0     0
#### [2,]    -1     1     0     0
#### [3,]     0     1     0     0
#### [4,]     0     0     1     0
#### [5,]     1     0     0     0
```

So to calculate the net flow per city I just have to do a matrix multiplication:

```
X %*% Z
####      city1 city2 city3 city4
#### [1,]    -5     5     7     0
#### [2,]    -3     5     8     0
#### ...
```

My problem is that there are lots of **missing values in my `X` matri**x (here 9 `NA`):

```
set.seed(3); for (i in 1:10) X[sample.int(nrow(X), 1), sample.int(ncol(X), 1)] <- NA
```

When I do the matrix multiplication the `NA` propagates to the whole row even if it is located on a zero value column (which does'nt impacts the sum). So I get 24 `NA` after the multiplication. However, if I do the calculation city by city only with the meters that are non-null, i only get 11 `NA`:

```
sum(is.na(cbind(X[, 1] - X[, 2] + X[, 5], X[, 2] + X[, 3], X[, 4], 0)))
#### [1] 11
```

I would like to know if there is a way **to do this calculation of the flows for each city that does'n propagate my `NA`** so much. In the reality my matrices are much bigger but a city is never alimented by more than 4 meters (it is quite *sparse*). i'd like to avoid coding each column by hand (because if there is any change in the network the script won't work anymore).
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I am sure this is what you need:

```
library(Matrix)
ZZ <- Matrix(Z, sparse = TRUE)
X %*% ZZ

#12 x 4 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
#      city1 city2 city3 city4
# [1,]    -5     5     7     0
# [2,]    NA    NA    NA     0
# [3,]    NA     6     8     0
# [4,]   -12    13     7     0
# [5,]    NA    NA     7     0
# [6,]   -13    10     6     0
# [7,]    -4    NA    NA     0
# [8,]    -1     2    NA     0
# [9,]    -6     1     5     0
#[10,]   -11     2     4     0
#[11,]    NA    NA     4     0
#[12,]    -5     1     4     0
```

As you expected, there are only 11 `NA`.

---

**Follow-up**

> It throws an error when I try to convert the result to a data frame: `data.frame(X %*% ZZ)`. How can I do it?

Use `data.frame(as.matrix(X %*% ZZ))`.

Comment: OK! It does the trick, thanks you made my day! But just one question: in my original code it throws an error when I try to convert the result back to a data.frame. How can I do it?